# What do I do with Atlas Stones?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I am following the Atlas Path and I have seen two stations. Both gave me an Atlas Stone. Are these important? Can I sell them or do I need to keep all of them for the eventual ending of the path? They are only 1 to a slot and getting more than a few will eventually cause some more inventory problems than I'd like.

Comment: I've read that there are major spoilers for their usage, just a heads up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Atlas Stone are used during the *Atlas Path* of the game.

[Atlas Stone](http://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Atlas_Stone) (spoilers, proceed with caution)

> After getting 10 Atlas stones and going to the next Atlas Interface you can make a new star, this will take all of your Atlas stones and say that you have created a new star. Current importance of this matter is unknown and it is unknown about what the effects of these actions are.

**Additional Information**

> Whatever you do, ***DO NOT SELL***. A buddy of mine made that mistake early on in the game, and sold two Atlas stones. When he made it to the final Atlas location, he was unable to proceed due to only have 8/10. Afterwards he was not able to locate any more Atlas locations to gather more stones. This may be a bug in the game, but no more information at this time

Comment: ugh that many inventory slots is super inconvient

Comment: Also for you buddy. I have seem them for sale at a station. So it is possible to get them outside of the story. (It cost 2million but its something)

Comment: @Reafexus Yeah, it sucks how they are not stackable and use up your inventory. I haven't seen them for sale, but I'll pass on the info too keep an eye out

Answer (score -2):

I threw away two of my Atlas Stones, and then later found some for sale from a random vy'keen alien, so you can buy them for sure.

Comment: sold 2 of my atlas stones and later found some for sale from a vy'keen warrior at a space station so you can buy en for sure