# Is it possible to get more Atlas Stones?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I was reading the following question when I realized that I had made a mistake while playing No Man's Sky:

[What do I do with Atlas Stones?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/281907/what-do-i-do-with-atlas-stones)

It seems that I sold some Atlas Stones before I learned that they were actually used for something.

I've heard from some sources that if you sell one of the stones, you're pretty much stuck with that decision as you'll never be able to get more. However, I've seen other sources mentioning that there are ways to get more Atlas Stones in case you lose or sell some.

Is it possible to get more Atlas Stones? How might I get more, since I sold one of mine?

Comment: It's my understanding that there is currently an exploit to duplicate your inventory, so you *could* get more that way, but be aware that it might be patched, and it might spoil your enjoyment to do something that essentially acts like cheat codes.

Comment: The exploit was patched for the PC before release, but may work for PS4 still.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, Atlas Stones can be received from Atlas Stations you find along your exploration. You can find them randomly, or they will likely be on your specific path to the center of the universe.

As to getting them randomly from around the systems and planets, I want to say no. However, you can buy them from some traders, albeit extremely overpriced (5+ Million Units).

Comment: They're 2.6 mil or so if you can get them from the market, and 5mil from most traders.

Answer (score 6):

Some traders will have Atlas stones for sale.  So far I personally have only seen a few for sale at space stations.  They are usually a couple million units each. I suspect you would have to shift paths to free explore, earn many units, and find more stones before you can continue back on to the goal that needs those stones.